# customize swiftkey layout

Tags: swiftkey

The title sums it up: how can we customize swiftkey layouts?

To ensure I don't do Y-X problem, my intention is to put an apostrophe (single quote) and median point on the main layout (abc keys, no modifier).

I expect we can retrieve the layouts somewhere, modify the one we want to our wishes, and push it back/ or at least push it to our device(s)?

Comment: According to Microsoft SwiftKey Support, [it's still not possible](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115001458785-How-to-change-keyboard-layout-to-my-own-custom-layout).

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndrewT. Sad, and the reasons evoked are pretty much laughable ("deep customize", "complicated to set up", really?!).
Anyway I hadn't found that entry, thanks.